# Select @xml.nodes ... how to assign column?

Tags: sql, xml

I want to put result of my xml.node sql into table and ran into this small problem like missing column name, can anybody recomend me.
This will break single file xml into  nodes, one node per one row..
this sample below works OK, but I need activate commented lines somehow:

```
--CREATE TABLE  TSxml  (TSNum INT IDENTITY (1,1),  xmlinfo XML)
--SELECT * FROM TSxml
declare @xml XML = (select c1 from t3)
--INSERT INTO TSxml 
--SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT T.N.query('.')
   FROM @xml.nodes('/testsuite') as T(N)
--) AS C1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing a column alias within your SELECT statement.  Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE  TSxml  (TSNum INT IDENTITY (1,1),  xmlinfo XML)
SELECT * FROM TSxml
declare @xml XML = (select c1 from t3)
INSERT INTO TSxml 
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT T.N.query('.') x
   FROM @xml.nodes('/testsuite') as T(N)
) AS C1
```